# For integer m greather than 2, $\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m+2}$, the numerators and denomitors are primitive pythagorean triples $a$ and $b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For $m = 2$, the fraction is $\frac{3}{4}$. for $m=3$, the fraction is$\frac{8}{15}$. I was wondering why numerators and demoninators of  $\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m+2}$ show primitive pythagorean triples a and b.

Comment: I posted an algebraic proof below, but would definitely be interested to see if there is a nicer geometric proof or something.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m+2}=\frac{2m+2}{m^2+2m}.$$ We can check that $$(m^2+2m)^2+(2m+2)^2=m^4+4m^3+4m^2+4m^2+8m+4=m^4+4m^3+8m^2+8m+4=(m^2+2m+2)^2.$$ Note that this is always a primitive triple if you put the fraction in lowest form, but $2m+2$ and $m^2+2m$ are not coprime in general (and thus the triple $2m+2,m^2+2m, m^2+2m+2$ is not primitive in general).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m+2} = \frac{2m+2}{m^2 + 2m}$$

Now notice that

$$(2m+2)^2 + (m^2 + 2m)^2=8m^2+4m+4+m^4+4m^3=(m^2+2m+2)^2$$

Comment: I believe your $x$s should be $m$s.

Comment: @helloworld112358 Yep, I've already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple form to proof:

$(m^2+2m)^2 + (2(m+1))^2 = ((m+1)^2 - 1)^2 + 4 (m+1)^2 = (m+1)^4 + 1 -2(m+1)^2 + 4(m+1)^2 = (m+1)^4 -2(m+1)^2 + 1 = ((m+1)^2 - 1)^2$